# Can't access SMART on an external HDD from gnome-disk-utility

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, gnome-disk-utility

I have a 2TB HDD connected by USB (WD Elements 25A2 (1014)) that I use to store my photos and as a Plex server on Ubuntu 16.04. I have been noticing it unmounting overnight recently for no particular reason, so I ran `sudo badblocks -nsv /dev/sdb1` and it told me that there were too many bad blocks to count.

However when I go to `gnome-disk-utility`, the option for "SMART Data & Self-Tests..." is grayed out. I can't figure out why. What can I do to access the SMART data?

Comment: Some SATA-USB interfaces/adapters do not support SMART.

Comment: Oh drat. How do I fix these bad blocks then?

Comment: Probably you need to connect it to a native SATA controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that some external hard drive interfaces do not support the SMART function. I have two interfaces/cases.  If I put a drive in one I get no support. Put the same drive in the other and SMART function works just fine.